# React Native justifyContent no effect

Tags: react-native

[image]

Figure, why setting the justifyContent property does not work?

Answer (score 1):

When you are in a container that has the flex direction set to 'row' then justify-content actually sets the location horizontally instead of vertically. So in this case you would use alignItems. Since the RN implementation of flexbox is pretty close to the standard baring a few naming differences ('flexDirection' instead of 'flex-direction', etc) I would recommend working your way through the tutorial at http://flexboxfroggy.com/. Level 10 actually shows an example of the issue you are encountering here.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `alignItems: 'center'`